# Spring Kafka get assigned partitions

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I know I can find out from which partition record comes in, but I wonder is any way to dynamically get which partitions are assigned for consumers at specific moment? Maybe I need to implement some listener to detect and follow up partitions assignation info?

I am using `spring-kafka 1.3.2` with `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` and `@KafkaListener`.

Comment: yeah, I believe I can solve my problem by implementing  ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener.

Comment: And how to do this with kafka streams? :))

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do:

```
@Bean
public ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener rebalanceListener() {
    return new ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onPartitionsAssigned(Consumer<?, ?> consumer, Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
           // here partitions
        }
    };
}
```

And then add it, for example, to ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();

    ContainerProperties props = factory.getContainerProperties();
    props.setConsumerRebalanceListener(rebalanceListener());

    return factory;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it in different way by using `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry`

```
for (MessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer : kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainers()) {
            List<KafkaMessageListenerContainer> containers = ((ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer) messageListenerContainer).getContainers();

            List<TopicPartition> topicPartitions = (List<TopicPartition>) containers.stream().flatMap(kafkaMessageListenerContainer ->
                            kafkaMessageListenerContainer.getAssignedPartitions().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());

            partitions.addAll(topicPartitions.stream().map(TopicPartition::partition).collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```