# What is the recommended way to obtain a list of all partitions that a ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer is currently handling

Tags: spring-kafka

I am looking for the best/recommended way to obtain a list of partitions that a `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer` is using while reading from a topic. Currently I am doing this manually, by having an implementation of `ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener` that is tracking assignments/revocations but I wonder whether there isn't a better/simpler way to achieve this.

The goal is to use this information within the application, so I always need an up-to-date list of partitions. Looking at the API for
`ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer`, I see that it is exposing
[getAssignedPartitions()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.html#getAssignedPartitions()).

A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48879578/spring-kafka-get-assigned-partitions) but there is no accepted answer until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer` is managed by `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry`, you could use `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry`  to get information about your listener containers through container's id and you could see the `ContainerProperties`, `AssignedPartitions`,... of this listener container.

Example of using `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#pause-resume

Comment: I followed your suggestion and tried something like:
```registry.getListenerContainer("my-container-id").getAssignedPartitions().stream()
   .map(tp -> tp.topic() + "-" + tp.partition())
   .collect(Collectors.toList());```
This yields the expected result, but is it also guaranteed to be always up-to-date?

Comment: you could see in the API document of `KafkaMessageListenerContainer.getAssignedPartitions`: Return the TopicPartitions currently assigned to this container. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/KafkaMessageListenerContainer.html#getAssignedPartitions()

Comment: Sounds reasonable.