# How to check a partition is assigned in Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to find out a way of checking if a partition is assigned before I do something on  that partition. We know the way to find if the consumer is assigned or not by checking

```
 consumer.assignment().isEmpty
```

But how I will do it to the partitions, my code is below

```
List<PartitionInfo> myPartitionInfo = consumer.partitionsFor(..);
mypartitionInfo.stream() 
   // before coming to this map i need to check if this partition is assigned
   .map(part->new TopicPartition(subTopicName,part.partition()))
   .......;
```

Is there any way i can do that? please suggest.

Comment: If you are using Spring - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48879578/spring-kafka-get-assigned-partitions

Comment: I don't know what you want me to edit. You're welcome to [edit] your post to show a [mcve]

Comment: Besides, if the partition is not assigned at all, then `myPartitionInfo` should not include it... Please clarify where that variable comes from

Comment: @OneCricketeer List<PartitionInfo> myPartitionInfo = consumer.partitionsFor(..); like this

Comment: What is wrong with `consumer.assignment()` or using `ConsumerRebalanceListener.onPartitionsAssigned` function?

Comment: @OneCricketeer i am not sure of how to use consumer.assignment() function to find if the partition is assigned or not. Can you give an example? That will be really great

Comment: Rather than using `consumer.partitionsFor()`, use `consumer.assignment()`. It returns the **currently assigned** partitions. What's the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already answered your own question. Use `consumer.assignment()`

```
// Data to check
String topic = "...";
int partition = 0;

// Check it
boolean isAssigned = consumer.assignment()
  .stream()
  .anyMatch(tp -> tp.topic().equals(topic) && tp.partition() == partition)
```

Otherwise, in your consumer poll loop, you also have acesss to the partition that each record comes from, and can check there.